# jquery ui, adjusting icon and background color on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have tried looking around and couldn't find any specific match to my problem.
I'm using jquery-ui v1.8.

I have a dialog that has tabs.  There are two types of tabs (ones w/ a close button and those without).  I'm trying to set the background color and icon color for those w/ a close button).

The jquery to create the tabs is as follows:

```
$('#mydivid').tabs({tabTemplate: 
    '<li><nobr><a href="#{href}">#{label}</a>' +
    '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></nobr></li>'});
$('#mydivid').show();
```

my .css is as follows:

```
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover 
{ color:white; background:#fb6648; cursor:pointer; }
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default
{ color:white; background:#5e8f9b; }
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus 
{ color:white; background:#fb6648; cursor:pointer; }
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active 
{ color:black; background:#e9ebe0; }
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon 
{background-image:url(image/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon 
{background-image:url(image/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon
{background-image:url(image/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);}
```

Without hovering my cursor, all the colors show up as I desire.  If I hover over the non-close tabs, it shows up as desired.  If I hover over a non-active tab, it shows up as desired.

On just the active tabs, when I hover, the  changes color and background as desired. BUT the icon doesn't change (as I would expect but not what I desire - I want the icon to change to white). If I hover over the icon OR the area behind it, that background doesn't change and the foreground color of the  reverts back to black (probably because I'm no longer hovering over the ) but the background remains orange.

So I'd like to change the icon color on the hover, have the background of the icon to change like the , and have the color on the  remain white when I hover the cursor over the close button.

I've tried many variations all to varying but non-successful degrees.  Please help.  I'm very new to jquery and CSS (as you can probably tell).

Comment: Do you think you could whip up a working example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Need to change the background image URL to the icons for white in your `:hover`.

Comment: I added the following to my css: .ui-state-active .ui-icon:hover (setting my url to the white icons) and that got the icon to turn white when I hover over it BUT if I'm over the X, then the <A> part goes back to black, if I hover over the <A>, then the X goes back to black, if I hover over just the background, they both go to black.

Comment: I also move the .ui-state-active above .ui-state-hover and that got the background to the correct color but now, after I'm no longer hovering, the active tab remains the hover color.